# Discord JS - importing a variable from another file's method

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have two commands: join and disconnect. Join function makes bot to join voice channel using method joinVoiceChannel, whilst disconnect command removes bot from the channel by using getVoiceConnection method:
**join.js**

```
const Command = require('../handlers/Command.js');
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "join",
    description: "Joins voice channel",

    async run(message, args, client) {
        const channel = message.member.voice.channel;
        if (!channel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a voice channel.');
        const permissions = channel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT') || !permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send("You don't have the right permission.");

        const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: channel.id,
            guildId: channel.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
        });
    }
});
```

**disconnect.js**

```
const Command = require('../handlers/Command.js');
const { getVoiceConnection } = require('@discordjs/voice');

module.exports = new Command({
    name: "disconnect",
    description: "Disconnects from the voice channel",

    async run(message, args, client) {
        try {
            const channel = message.member.voice.channel;
            const connection = getVoiceConnection(channel.guild.id);
            connection.destroy();
        } catch (error) { }
    }
});
```

Can I somehow import the connection constant from **join.js** to **disconnect.js** to avoid using other methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 simple ways to access `connection` without the need to export and require:

1. Hoist to the Discord Client object. This way you can access `connection` as long as you have access to your Discord Client (typically by `client` or `message.client`). Of course this will only be available once the `join.js` command is executed atleast once, before that happens `client.connection` will be `undefined`

```js
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
   channelId: channel.id,
   guildId: channel.guild.id,
   adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
});

client.connection = connection;

// You can now use client.connection in any file that has client defined
```

2. Hoist to the `global` object. Similar to #1, however the `connection` variable gets hoisted with the enviroment's `global` object which is accessible to *all* JavaScript files in the node enviroment.

```js
const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
   channelId: channel.id,
   guildId: channel.guild.id,
   adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
});

global.connection = connection;
```